# I filled small gaps in the proof of Theorem 16.4 on p.91 in "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres. Is my proof ok?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am reading "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres.
I read the proof of Theorem 16.4 on p.91 and the proof was difficult for me.
So, I filled very small gaps in the proof and rewrote the proof.
Is my proof ok?

> **Theorem 16.4.** $\,\,\,\,\,$Let $X$ be an ordered set in the order topology; let $Y$ be a subset of $X$ that is convex in $X$. Then the order topology on $Y$ is the same as the topology $Y$ inherits as a subspace of $X$.
> *Proof.*$\,\,\,\,\,$Consider the ray $(a,+\infty)$ in $X$. What is its intersection with $Y$? If $a\in Y$, then $$(a,+\infty)\cap Y=\{x\mid x\in Y \text{ and }x>a\};$$ this is an open ray of the ordered set $Y$. If $a\notin Y$, then $a$ is either a lower bound on $Y$ or an upper bound on $Y$, since $Y$ is convex. In the former case, the set $(a,+\infty)\cap Y$ equals all of $Y$; in the latter case, it is empty.
> $\,\,\,\,\,$A similar remark shows that the intersection of the ray $(-\infty,a)$ with $Y$ is either an open ray of $Y$, or $Y$ itself, or empty. Since the sets $(a,+\infty)\cap Y$ and $(-\infty,a)\cap Y$ form a subbasis for the subspace topology on $Y$, and since each is open in the order topology, the order topology contains the subspace topology.
> $\,\,\,\,\,$To prove the reverse, note that any open ray of $Y$ equals the intersection of an open ray of $X$ with $Y$, so it is open in the subspace topology on $Y$. Since the open rays of $Y$ are a subbasis for the order topology on $Y$, this topology is contained in the subspace topology.

I filled small gaps in the above proof:
My proof:

> Proposition 1:
> The sets $(a,+\infty)\cap Y$ and $(-\infty,a)\cap Y$ form a subbasis for the subspace topology on $Y$, where $(a,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty,a)$ are open rays in $X$.
> Proof:
> Let $y$ be an arbitrary element of $Y$.
> Since $X$ has more than one element by the definition of the order topology on p.84, there exists $a\in X$ such $a<y$ or $y<a$.
> So, $y\in (a,+\infty)$ or $y\in (-\infty,a)$ for some $a\in X$.
> So, $y\in (a,+\infty)\cap Y$ or $y\in (-\infty,a)\cap Y$ for some $a\in X$.
> So, the sets $(a,+\infty)\cap Y$ and $(-\infty,a)\cap Y$ form a subbasis for a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $Y$.
> We prove $\mathcal{T}$ equals the subspace topology on $Y$.
> By Lemma 16.1 on p.89, the sets $(a,b)\cap Y$ and $[a_0,b)\cap Y$ and $(a,b_0]\cap Y$ form a basis for the subspace topology on $Y$, where $(a,b)$ and $[a_0,b)$ and $(a,b_0]$ are intervals in $X$ and $a_0$ is the smallest element (if any) of $X$ and $b_0$ is the largest element (if any) of $X$.
> Since $(a,b)\cap Y=((a,+\infty)\cap Y)\cap ((-\infty,b)\cap Y)$ and $[a_0,b)\cap Y=(-\infty,b)\cap Y$ and $(a,b_0]\cap Y=(a,+\infty)\cap Y$, any element of the subspace topology on $Y$ is an element of $\mathcal{T}$.
> Since $(a,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty,a)$ are open sets of $X$ (See p.86), $(a,+\infty)\cap Y$ and $(-\infty,a)\cap Y$ are elements of the subspace topology on $Y$.
> So, any element of $\mathcal{T}$ is an element of the subspace topology on $Y$.

> Proposition 2:
> $(a,+\infty)\cap Y$ and $(-\infty,a)\cap Y$ are open in the order topology on $Y$.
> Proof:
> For example, let $X:=\mathbb{R}$ and $Y:=[0,1]\cup [2,3]$.
> Then, $(\frac{3}{2},+\infty)\cap Y=[2,3]$ is not open in the order topology on $Y$.
> So, we need to prove the proposition 2.
> If $a\in Y$, then $(a,+\infty)\cap Y=\{x\mid x\in Y \text{ and }x>a\}$ is an open ray of the orderd set $Y$.
> So, $(a,+\infty)\cap Y$ is open in the order topology on $Y$ (See p.86).
> If $a\notin Y$, then $a$ is either a lower bound on $Y$ or an upper bound on $Y$.
> We prove this.
> Assume that $a$ is not a lower bound on $Y$ and $a$ is not an upper bound on $Y$.
> Then, there exist $y_1,y_2\in Y$ such that $y_1<a<y_2$.
> Since $Y$ is convex in $X$, $a\in Y$.
> This is a contradiction.
> If $a$ is a lower bound on $Y$, then $(a,+\infty)\cap Y=Y$.
> So, in this case $(a,+\infty)\cap Y$ is open in the order topology on $Y$.
> If $a$ is an upper bound on $Y$, then $(a,+\infty)\cap Y=\emptyset$.
> So, in this case $(a,+\infty)\cap Y$ is open in the order topology on $Y$.
> Similarly we can show that $(-\infty,a)\cap Y$ is open in the order topology on $Y$.

> Proposition 3:
> Any open ray of $Y$ is open in the subspace topology on $Y$.
> Proof:
> We can write any open ray of $Y$ as $(a,+\infty)\cap Y$ or $(-\infty,a)\cap Y$ for some $a\in Y$.
> Since $(a,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty,a)$ are open in $X$ (See p.86), any open ray of $Y$ is open in the subspace topology on $Y$.

> Proposition 4:
> The open rays of $Y$ are a subbasis for the order topology on $Y$.
> Proof:
> See p.86.

> From proposition 1 and proposition 2, it is obvious that the order topology on $Y$ contains the subspace topology on $Y$.
> From proposition 3 and proposition 4, it is obvious that the subspace topology on $Y$ contains the order topology on $Y$.

Comment: Have you looked at [my own proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1778691/4280) as an inspiration? I did not use the Munkres' proof for it, just first principles.

Comment: Similarly we have a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3559486/4280) as well.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you very much for your links to your answers.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Your proof checks that $(a,b)\cap Y$ and $[\min(X),a)\cap Y$ and $(a,\max(X)]\cap Y$ belongs to $\mathcal{T}_{<Y}$ directly. Very nice proof. Thank you very much.